# The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Error launching WinPTY agent: agent executable does not exist: '

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules, launching, winpty

[image]The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Error launching WinPTY agent: agent executable does not exist: '\?\C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\node-pty\build\Release\winpty-agent.exe').